# Is there is a way to use adjusted bounce rate and the standard one simulataneously?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to adjust the Google Analytics bounce rate for my website as the standard calculation is not very indicative. At the same time, it is desirable to find a way to leave the standard bounce rate calculation as well to make an accurate comparison with prior periods. Is there a way to do it through calculated metrics or other advanced GTM and GA features? I don't think so but need confirmation

Answer (score 1):

There is a BETA feature, called Calculated Metrics. You can create custom calculated values based on other existing numeric values. This a view level setting.

You haven't specified, what data you would include in your calculation, but this might give you an eample, how you can create your own Bounce rate calculation:

[image]

You will also need to create custom reports to use these metrics.

Comment: The idea is to adjust the bounce rate on the resource level using GTM timer and scrolling listeners, but I am interested if there is a way to keep the old bounce rate calculation as well. Bounce rate is calculated as one-interaction sessions/all sessions. I am aware of calculated metric functionality but don't think there is a way to recreate the standard bounce calculations after adjusting the bounce rate at the GA resource level.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are referring to calculated metrics as a general concept, not as the GA feature. You could create a duplicate property, and use it to send interaction events only to this copied property, and keep all other settings and data collections in sync with your original property. Not the most convenient way, but gets you the comparable data.

Comment: yeah, I thought about creating separate property..but I am little nervous about consequences as we have many tags, triggers, and variables and I am afraid that using separate property can cause some conflicts